# Python subprocess не могу убить процесс

Tags: python

Хочу убить процесс Bandicam в Python

Код:

```
process = subprocess.Popen("bandicam/bandicam.exe")
time.sleep(20)
process.kill()
```

kill и terminate не срабатывают, bandicam как работал, так и работает

Update:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужно в windows убить процесс, верно?

Comment: @nick_gabpe да.

Comment: У вас точно нет shell =True?

Comment: @nick_gabpe что эта команда значит?

Comment: subprocess.Popen("bandicam/bandicam.exe", shell=True) запускает дочерний процесс так что sigkill не доходит до него. Без shell=True sigkill и sigterm работают нормально  и завершают процесс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте тяжелую артиллерию:

```
import ctypes
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
PROCESS_TERMINATE = 1

process = subprocess.Popen("bandicam/bandicam.exe")
time.sleep(20)
handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, int(process.pid))
ctypes.windll.kernel32.TerminateProcess(handle, -1)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
```

Вариант прибивания всего дерева процессов взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4229404/9921853):

```
import psutil, os

def kill_proc_tree(pid, including_parent=True):    
    parent = psutil.Process(pid)
    children = parent.children(recursive=True)
    for child in children:
        child.kill()
    gone, still_alive = psutil.wait_procs(children, timeout=5)
    if including_parent:
        parent.kill()
        parent.wait(5)


process = subprocess.Popen("bandicam/bandicam.exe")

time.sleep(20)

process.kill()

PROCNAME = "Bandicam_Portable.exe"
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
        kill_proc_tree(proc.pid)
        break
```

---

### Добавлено

Важный момент, когда процесс не прибивается без видимых причин, следует обращать внимание на его PID и задаваться вопросом, а его ли мы пытаемся прибить.

Процесс, который Вы запускаете, клонирует себя в демон-режиме, то есть отсоединяется от родительского процесса и уже потом из-под себя запускает подпроцессы. Это ему позволяет остаться в живых даже когда Ваш скрипт завершён.

Соответственно, склонированный процесс получает свой собственный PID, который нам не известен.

Интересно, что тот процесс, PID которого получается из `subprocess.Popen`, тоже живет, причем не виден в менеджере задач и в `Process Explorer`.

Решение такое.

1. Использовать `process.kill()`, чтобы прибить стартовый процесс
2. Найти PID отпочковавшегося процесса по его имени `Bandicam_Portable.exe` и прибить всё дерево.

Работает на ура. Код - выше

Comment: Нет. Может его нельзя убить, пока запись активна?

Comment: @danilshik Я бы загрузил [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) и проверил, что именно этот процесс порождает. А ещё проверил, убиваем ли он из Task Manager и из Process Explorer. И ещё, я в примере не указывал, но какой код ошибки возвращает `TerminateProcess`?

Comment: а как проверить? просто в print вывести? Если да, то возвращает 0

Comment: Task Manager в Windows процесс убивает

Comment: @SergetNudnov добавил скриншот. Если я закрою только верхний уровень, то bandicam не закроется, а только запись приостановится, если закрыть все дерево, то bandicam закрывается

Comment: @danilshik, добавил вариант для всего дерева процессов

Comment: а как запускать? me = os.getpid()
kill_proc_tree(me) после моего запуска вставлять, time.sleep()?

Comment: @danilshik `kill_proc_tree(process.pid)` после `time.sleep(20)` Это же просто функция и ниже - пример её использования

Comment: тогда не сработало, вернуло код 15

Comment: @danilshik Приду домой - посмотрю что за монстра Вы запускаете. До завтра!

Comment: @danilshik Вопрос решен, обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо, работает

Answer (score 0):

Так он точно убьёт процесс.

```
process = subprocess.Popen("bandicam/bandicam.exe")
subprocess.Popen("taskkill -f -t -pid {0} ".format(process.pid))
```

Comment: как узнать proc.id?

Comment: Вывело �訡��: �� 㤠���� ���� ����� "9472"., но bandicam не умер

Comment: А если добавить -t ?

Comment: @nick_gabre нет=(